# Importing Flash project into Flash Builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I am on a mac and I have a preexisting Flash project. (i.e usual fla, src, lib) folders.
Now, I want to start writing the code using Flash Builder 4.

How do I import all those files so I can now develop in Flash Builder 4?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.  Just need to do File > New > Flex Project to define a project for the folder containing your app.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this, I have a file with .fla extension, what is required to check the code in FLash Builder, I cant seem to import it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder cannot open fla files. If your code is pure actionscript, you can create new project and remake it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flash Builder 4 to open and run Flex Builder 3 projects.  The 3.5 SDK comes as part of the Flash Builder 4 install.  If you have pure actionscript files, and don't have a 3.5 project, then you can always create a new project, then copy in your directory structure.  It shouldn't be too painful, but you probably want to move some of your prior actionscript into mxml for your views to take advantage of its conciseness in describing views.