# Open Flash project in Flash Builder/Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing Flash project into Flash Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109405/importing-flash-project-into-flash-builder)

Can you use Flash Builder 4 to package an AIR app project previously created in Flash?